# Android - Audio get a float[] from Uri

Tags: android, audio, uri

I have an audio file which I get from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` as an Uri and return it like this:

```
Uri song;
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SONG_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if ((data != null) && (data.getData()!=null)) {
                song = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }
```

For another library I found, I need to pass the song as a `float[]`

What would be a way to convert it?

Comment: What is song? And what is its value?

Comment: @greenapps Song is an Uri and its value is set on line 6: song = data.getData()

Comment: Yes its value is set there. I already saw that of course.  But then what is its value? So song.toString() and song.getPath() please.

Comment: @greenapps It's the user who selects the file to work with, so both, toString() and getPath() will depend on which file the user chooses

Comment: Yes i know. You dont have to teach me the obvious. Just give some examples.

Comment: I don't know some specific example. I don't actually get what you're asking I'm sorry. If you need it for an answer just write some random path.

Comment: No. You should give me examples. You write the app. So you test it by selecting files. Now give values of .toString() and .getPath().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152790/discussion-between-daniele-and-greenapps).

Comment: No. Give examples.

Comment: @greenapps Listen. I don't know what examples to give. I asked for something specific. Which, as you surely will know since I don't have to teach you nothing, doesn't need an example to be explained. Furthermore the song variable is based solely on the user selected file so the example would be toString =  // the string representation of the uri and getPath() = the path to the file the Uri refers to, Which beeing it user-based can be any String and any path. So please if you want to help me get some random string and some random path. It's gonna be fine, Otherwise don't worry. Thank you.

Comment: Daniele, I suggest when someone is trying to help you that you cooperate with them, even if their request seems silly - it demonstrates good faith on your part, and may well help them get more invested in helping you.

Comment: @AaronHall you are right and I&#39;m grateful for people trying to help me out of course, that's what SO is all about. I wanted to start a discussion to explain him that I did not have the project with me and that in any case the toString and getPath would return the standard values they&#39;d return for any file, since it&#39;s up to the user to choose the file the Uri refers to. And all I got.as an answer was &quot;No. Send example&quot;. That is really rude, because I was willing to explain and he did not.give me a chance.